# Problems setting max-width for a whole website?

Tags: html, css, web

I understand that max-width has been very well documented, but I am still having trouble making my website stop stretching at a certain point.  When the user stretches the browser more than 800 px, I want my website to stop stretching.  (All my divs and everything are done in %'s, not px's.) I created a wrapper,

```css
#wrapper{
    max-width:800px;
}
```

However, because my divs are absolutely positioned, it does not move them, and when I make their positions relative, the website looks very messy.  I would love some help, and could provide more code if you need it.  I think the main problem is in the absolute positioning.

Comment: We definitely need some more detail to be able to help you out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add `position: relative` to your parent wrapper

```css
#wrapper {
    max-width:800px;
    position: relative;
}
```

The following fiddle illustrates the difference between relative and absolute positioning:

## [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/pFeYa/)

See [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) from CSS-Tricks for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries, they allow you to target specific resolution ranges, for example, if you want your website to stop stretching or even wear a new style when the screen is between 800px and 1200px, you can use this:

Standard strylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" />
```

Media queried stylesheet:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1200px)' href='stylesheet.css' />
```

Most of responsive websites use this technique to load specific styles when user comes from a tablet or smartphone.
Try it out.

Comment: I am interested in your idea, but I can't see your code. Do you mind editing it so I can see it? Thanks